# iOS memory management - clarifications

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, memory-management, dealloc

I know that `alloc` and `retain` will increase the reference count of an object. Is there any other different method that actually increment the reference count? And when/how does `dealloc` is called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With these the retain count gets increased.

1. new, however it can be seen as alloc+init.
2. retain
3. copy creates new object with retain count=1
4. mutableCopy creates new object with retain count=1

`dealloc` is called automatically as soon as retain count reaches to 0.

Comment: Don't `copy` and `mutableCopy` create new objects with retain count 1? They don't increase the retain count of the receiver.

Comment: @DrummerB: "Don't copy and mutableCopy create new objects with retain count 1" No, not necessarily. They can also just increase the retain count of the receiver.

Comment: @DrummerB: plus the point is that methods that start with `alloc`, `new`, `retain`, `copy`, or `mutableCopy` return a retaining instance. It is irrelevant what object it is called on.

Answer (score 7):

- `alloc` allocates an object with retain count 1.
- Methods that start with `new` also return an object with retain count 1.
- `retain` increments the count by 1.
- `release` and `autorelease` (at the end of the run loop) decrement it by 1.
- Methods that start with the name of the class (without prefix) return an autoreleased object, meaning that it will be released at the end of the cycle, if you don't retain it yourself.
- Finally, methods that copy an object (usually start with `copy`) also create a copy with retain count 1.

`dealloc` is called when the retain count of an object drops to 0.

PS. In case you didn't know about it yet, consider using [Automatic Reference Counting (ARC)](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Comment: 1. Add `mutableCopy` as well, 2. not "at the end of the run loop" (what does that even mean?), but at the end of the enclosing autorelease pool. +1 though.

Comment: @H2CO3, the default autorelease pool does release objects in the pool at the end of each run loop cycle. However, that's not true for user-created autorelease pools, nor should it be counted on. It's probably better to think in terms of autoreleased objects lasting until the end of the outermost enclosing scope that is part of your code (unless you've explicitly created an autorelease pool, e.g. for a tight loop with lots of object allocations).

Comment: @AndrewMadsen that's the end of the **cycle** then, not the end of the run loop.

Comment: @H2CO3, indeed, the wording in the answer isn't quite correct, but it certainly seems that that's what DrummerB meant.

Comment: it's called `Reference Count`, not retain count.  Retain counts were an awful side-effect of manual memory management that could report values anywhere from 0 to -UINT_MAX for no darn good reason.

Comment: @CodaFi I'm pretty sure Apple calls it retain count in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmPractical.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004447-SW2), but it looks like both terms are ok.

Comment: That's the bit I was talking about.  Create a static NSString and query it for it's retainCount.  If you're lucky, you get 1, but usually you get UINT_MAX.

Comment: I didn't say `retainCount`, but retain count. I didn't mean the method. Everyone knows [you are not supposed to rely on `retainCount`](http://whentouseretaincount.com/).

Comment: "Finally, methods that copy an object (usually start with copy) also create a copy with retain count 1." Not necessarily. They could just retain.

Comment: @CodaFi: It is *retain count*, as in `-retainCount`. What DrummerB said is the the default behavior of `retain`, etc. inherited from `NSObject`. There are some specialized classes whose `retain`, etc. methods override that behavior and do different things to the retain count, e.g. for singletons, static strings, class objects, etc.

Comment: @DrummerB: "I didn't say retainCount, but retain count." `-retainCount` *is* the "retain count". "you are not supposed to rely on `-retainCount`" means "you are not supposed to rely on the retain count"

Comment: All I'm saying is that there's a reason it ain't called automatic retain counting